# Sci-fi short, a miniature town/people used for testing advertisements?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, androids

Many years ago I read a short story about a man who figures out that his world is not real but an artificial miniature, populated by artificial people and used to test advertisements, etc. The "real" people then ask him if he'd rather go back to not knowing.

I thought he also found a tape in his body controlling his reality, but that seems to be another short story, "The Electric Ant" by Philip K. Dick.

Anyone know the title?

Comment: If you were mixing these up, you might have read the collection "Space Odyssey" which had both (as well as a lot of other good stories).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"The Tunnel Under the World" (1955) by Frederik Pohl?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tunnel_under_the_World) reports the ending:

> In actuality, the chemical plant had exploded, and all the inhabitants of Tylerton were killed by the explosion or the chemical fumes. A ruthless advertising executive, Dorchin, took over the ruins and rebuilt them in miniature. The people were rebuilt as minuscule robots and are being used as captive subjects for testing high pressure advertising campaigns.

Answer (score 5):

This is "[Tunnel Under the World](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45822)" (1955) by Frederik Pohl, first published in *Galaxy Science Fiction*, January 1955.  You can read the story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v09n04_1955-01/page/n7/mode/2up).

The town is used to test advertisements:

> The sheaf he handed Swanson was headed: "Test Area Progress Report. Subject: Marlin Cigarettes Campaign." It was mostly tabulated figures that made little sense to Burckhardt and Swanson. but at the end was a summary that said:
>
> > Although Test 47-K3 pulled nearly double the number of new users of any of the other tests conducted, it probably cannot be used in the field because of local sound-truck control ordinances. [...]
>
> Swanson looked up from the paper into Burckhardt's eyes. "I don't get it." he complained.
>
> Burckhardt said, "I don't blame you. It's crazy, but it fits the facts, Swanson, it fits the facts. They aren't Russians and they aren't Martians. These people are advertising men! Somehow — heaven knows how they did it — they've taken Tylerton over. They've got us, all of us, you and me and twenty or thirty thousand other people, right under their thumbs."

They try to take over the town from Dorchin, only to discover they're robots:

> There was no pulse, but there was a rhythmic ticking of the outstretched fingers of one hand.
>
> There was no sound of breathing, but there was a hissing, sizzling noise.
>
> The eyes were open and they were looking at Burckhardt. There was neither fear nor pain in them, only a pity deeper than the Pit.
>
> She said, through lips that writhed erratically, "Don't — worry, Mr. Burckhardt. I'm — all right."
>
> Burckhardt rocked back on his haunches, staring. Where there should have been blood, there was a clean break of a substance that was not flesh; and a curl of thin golden-copper wire.
>
> Burckhardt moistened his lips. "You're a robot," he said.
>
> The girl tried to nod. The twitching lips said, "I am. And so are you."

He finally discovers he's been miniaturized and is "living" on a tabletop:

> No wonder Dorchin could so easily give him his freedom! From the factory, there was nowhere to go — but how incredible this fantastic gulf, how impossible the hundred white and blinding suns that hung above!
>
> A voice by his side said inquiringly, “Burckhardt?” And thunder rolled the name, mutteringly soft, back and forth in the abyss before him.
>
> Burckhardt wet his lips. "Y-yes?" he croaked.
> "This is Dorchin. Not a robot this time, but Dorchin in the flesh, talking to you on a hand mike. Now you have seen, Burckhardt. Now will you be reasonable and let the maintenance crews take over?"
>
> Burckhardt stood paralyzed. One of the moving mountains in the blinding glare came toward him.
>
> It towered hundreds of feet over his head; he stared up at its top, squinting helplessly into the light.
>
> It looked like —
>
> Impossible!
>
> The voice in the loudspeaker at the door said, "Burckhardt?" But he was unable to answer.
>
> A heavy rumbling sigh. "I see," said the voice. "You finally understand. There's no place to go. You know it now. I could have told you, but you might not have believed me, so it was better for you to see it yourself. And after all, Burckhardt, why would I reconstruct a city just the way it was before? I'm a businessman; I count costs. If a thing has to be full-scale, I build it that way. But there wasn't any need to in this case."
>
> From the mountain before him. Burckhardt helplessly saw a lesser cliff descend carefully toward him. It was long and dark, and at the end of it was whiteness, five-fingered whiteness...
>
> "Poor little Burckhardt," crooned the loudspeaker, while the echoes rumbled through the enormous chasm that was only a workshop. "It must have been quite a shock for you to find out you were living in a town built on a table top."